# "Component is missing template or render function" when unit testing Vue 3 component using Jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3

I'm attempting to upgrade a Vue 2 project into a Vue 3 project. This project uses webpack, and does not use vue-cli or Vite.

I installed the Vue 3 compatibility build initially and was able to build and serve my application, but I am unable to unit test any components.

Whenever I try to run my `.spec.ts` or `.spec.js` tests, I get the following warning printed to the console:

```
console.warn
    [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
      at <Anonymous ref="VTU_COMPONENT" > 
      at <VTUROOT>
```

The tests then fails.

My component was initially written using the `script setup` syntax using TypeScript. I have removed this and most of the functionality (so as to provide a minimal, reproducible example) to make sure that this isn't interfering, but I am still receiving the same error. I have also changed the test so that the test is as basic as possible.

My edited component:

```js
//CloseButton.vue

<template>
    <p>Hey what is up</p>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {},
});
</script>

<style scoped>
svg.close-icon {
    height: 1.125em;
    width: 1.125em;
}

.close-button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

```js
//CloseButton.spec.js

import CloseButton from '/components/CloseButton/CloseButton.vue';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

describe('CloseButton.vue', () => {
    it('renders the close button', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(CloseButton, {});

        expect(wrapper.find('p').exists()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

```js
//jest.config.js
/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.InitialOptions} */
const config = {
    verbose: true,
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'js',
        'json',
        'ts',
        'tsx',
        // tell Jest to handle `*.vue` files
        'vue',
    ],
    transform: {
        '.*\\.(vue)$': '@vue/vue3-jest',
        '.*\\.(js)$': 'babel-jest',
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
        '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\\?inline)?$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^/components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components/$1',
        '^@/(.*)$': 'src',
    },
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageReporters: ['json', 'html'],
    collectCoverageFrom: ['**/*.{js,ts,vue}', '!**/node_modules/**'],
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
        'dist',
        'node_modules',
        'build',
        'config',
        'coverage',
        '.eslintrc.js',
        '.postcssrc.js',
        'tests',
        'main.js',
    ],
    snapshotSerializers: ['jest-serializer-vue'],
    reporters: ['default', 'jest-junit'],
    testEnvironmentOptions: {
        customExportConditions: ['node', 'node-addons'],
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```

```json
//jsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "src/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

When the test does not involve a component (say, when testing a composable), the tests pass like normal. It just seems that my project doesn't understand how to transform a vue component correctly.

Please let me know if you need anything more to help solve this problem!